# Error while working with SpeechRecognition Library

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio, portaudio

I am trying to make a speech to text program using the PyAudio and SpeechRecognition libraries,
but I keep getting this error while running it, pls help with this [this is the error i am getting]

```
source activate base
/Users/praveersinghmehroke/anaconda3/bin/python "/Users/praveersinghmehroke/Desktop/Virtual Assistant/main2.py"
(base) praveersinghmehroke@192 Virtual Assistant % source activate base
(base) praveersinghmehroke@192 Virtual Assistant % /Users/praveersinghmehroke/anaconda3/bin/python "/Users/praveersinghmehroke/Desktop/Virtual Assistant/main2.py"
||PaMacCore (AUHAL)|| Error on line 1277: err='-66748', msg=Unknown Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/praveersinghmehroke/Desktop/Virtual Assistant/main2.py", line 8, in get_audio
    recorder.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
  File "/Users/praveersinghmehroke/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 383, in adjust_for_ambient_noise
    assert source.stream is not None, "Audio source must be entered before adjusting, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?"
AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before adjusting, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/praveersinghmehroke/Desktop/Virtual Assistant/main2.py", line 16, in <module>
    get_audio()
  File "/Users/praveersinghmehroke/Desktop/Virtual Assistant/main2.py", line 7, in get_audio
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/Users/praveersinghmehroke/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 189, in __exit__
    self.stream.close()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
(base) praveersinghmehroke@192 Virtual Assistant %
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJECX.jpg)

[this is the code i am running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvR1I.png)

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio


def get_audio():
    recorder = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        recorder.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Say something...")
        audio = recorder.listen(source)
    
    text = recorder.recognize_google(audio)
    print("You said: "+ str(text))
    return text

get_audio()
```

I am on a macOS Monterey (12.0) machine , with pyaudio, portaudio and SpeechRecognition installed.

After reading some stuff on the web , I tried to fix issue with MacBook built in microphone  (as I am using that for audio input) by restarting the machine , but that didn't work .

Also I tried to specify device_index attribute also , but that did'nt work too . Also the permission of microphone access to VSCode is also enabled.

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: oh sorry, didnt know about it ,

Comment: done,  using the { } formatting tool